# How to load grid view on check box selection?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 Grid views and 1 check box on web page( ASP.net,C# ). If check box is selected I want to load grid view 1 ,if unchecked want to load grid view 2 instead grid view 1 and vice versa.

Comment: Better if you add what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `AutoPostBack="true"` so the `CheckBox` causes a postback when it gets clicked and you need to call the event `OnCheckedChanged` when your `CheckBox` was checked

ASP:

```
<asp:CheckBox  ID="mycheckbox" runat="server" 
OnCheckedChanged="mycheckbox_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

C#

```
protected void mycheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mycheckbox.Checked)
    {
        //load GridView 1
    }
    else
    {
        //load GridView 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
    if(CheckBox1.Checked==true)
    {
        grid1 bind here
    }
    else
    {
        grid bind here
    }
```

or

```
    if(CheckBox1.Checked)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
```